# A single Selenuim test fails under jenkins

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

When I run my `Selenium` test suite under `Jenkins` a test fails.

If I run the same `test suite` from the command prompt they all pass.

When running from the command prompt, I'm in  the `Jenkins worskpace`. This where the Jenkins runs Selenium from.

Has anyone got any ideas as to why this maybe?

Comment: Please post your error

Comment: You need to provide some more details. Keep this habit friend!

Comment: We have lots of ideas if you would share your: 1) HTML source code of the page being tested (get it locally is ok) 2) Application Code 3) Test code, then we can probably help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

When we execute automation script/tests using Jenkins -

- Cross check whether you have provided few hard-coded location paths?
- If you are creating reports you need to check whether you have required access permissions to read, write & execute?
- Similarly, If you are taking screen-shots of failed tests, ensure you are having all access permission

I will surely update my answer, once more details will be provided for question.